# Subsetting multiple rows from same column based on condition in additional column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, filtering, data-manipulation

I am trying to get a subset of my data that includes two different values for a single column that match to a second column using data.table.

This feels like a fairly trivial task, yet I have been unable to find an example like this anywhere:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(id = c("100", "100", "101", "101", "101", "103", "105", "105"),
                  V1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B"),
                  V2 = c(NA, NA, 20, NA, 30, NA, 30, 30))
```

What I am trying to do is find all instances where both A and B are NA for a given id.

I can get the id's for which either is true easily:

```
dat[(V1 == "A" & is.na(V2)) | (V1 == "B" & is.na(V2)), ] # works as expected

# id V1 V2
# 1: 100  A NA
# 2: 100  B NA
# 3: 101  B NA
# 4: 103  B NA

dat[V1 %in% c("A", "B") & is.na(V2), ] # same as above
```

But if I try to combine the call with &, it doesn't work

```
dat[(V1 == "A" & is.na(V2)) & (V1 == "B" & is.na(V2)), ] # empty data table
dat[(V1 == "A" & is.na(V2)) && (V1 == "B" & is.na(V2)), ] # empty data table
```

I suppose the data.table is empty because there are no rows for which V1 is equal to A AND B, but nothing I have tried comes close.

This is what I am trying to get out:

```
# id V1 V2
# 1: 100  A NA
# 2: 100  B NA
```

I suppose I need to include the id information in some way here, but it is not clear to me how because adding `by =` doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select those groups that have both the `'A'` and `'B'` value and both of them are `NA`.

```
library(data.table)

dat[, .SD[all(c('A', 'B') %in% V1 & is.na(V2[match(c('A', 'B'), V1)]))], id]

#    id V1 V2
#1: 100  A NA
#2: 100  B NA
```

Comment: and also `dat[is.na(V2), .SD[all(c("A", "B") %chin% V1)], id]`

Answer (score 1):

i recommend using @Ronak Shah's answer - i just add this because it was fun to play around with and may be easier to understand if you (like me) still work on your understanding of the data table syntax

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c("100", "100", "101", "101", "101", "103", "105", "105"),
                  V1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B"),
                  V2 = c(NA, NA, 20, NA, 30, NA, 30, 30))

dat <- dat[(dat$V1 == "A" & is.na(dat$V2)) | (dat$V1 == "B" & is.na(dat$V2)), ] 

#find all id's that exist more than once
non_unique<-as.data.frame(table(dat$id))
non_unique<-non_unique[non_unique$Freq>1,]

dat<-dat[dat$id %in% as.character(non_unique[,1]),]
dat

   id V1 V2
1 100  A NA
2 100  B NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get what you need, but have you tried this way?

```
dat[(V1 %in% c("A", "B") & is.na(V2)),]
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but without the wrapping parentheses. When I add the parentheses, I still get the same output that includes the extra id's (101 and 103 in my example from above)